# Where does the init *really* happen in a UIView placed in Interface builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit

I have a subclass of UIView called SlideOut. I want to capture the IB placement of the view when it loads, so I have this in my implementation:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    IBframe.origin.x = frame.origin.x;
  IBframe.origin.y = frame.origin.y;
  IBframe.size.height = frame.size.height;
     IBframe.size.width = frame.size.width;
        // Initialization code.
  NSLog(@"init if self x: %f, y: %f", IBframe.origin.x, IBframe.origin.y);
    }
 NSLog(@"init x: %f, y: %f", IBframe.origin.x, IBframe.origin.y);
    return self;
}
```

... with a matching prototype in the .h file.

Upon starting up the simulator, I get all my other diagnostics, but neither of these log messages get called. So how does the instance *actually* get initialized? Or am I missing something? The position function works, but then fails because I haven't captured the actual frame of the thing. In any case, that's how I know I made the IB connections correctly.

Comment: Are you sure initWithFrame is being called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look here: [Subclassing UIView, "Methods to Override", from UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3).

In particular:

> initWithCoder: - Implement this method
>   if you load your view from an
>   Interface Builder nib file and your
>   view requires custom initialization.

Comment: Now to go read in greater depth and see if I want to do this in a different place. Thanks everyone, this was one of those flash frustrations which narrows your view, which blinded me to an answer that was inches away. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5):

Objects that are loaded from an xib are actually unarchived. Thus, you should be using the `initWithCoder:` method. Alternatively, you may way to look at `awakeFromNib` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the function that gets called when the view is loaded from a NIB is `initWithCoder` not `initWithFrame`